# Mahout Matrix Factorization Recommender on Hadoop is extremely slow

Tags: hadoop, mahout, matrix-factorization

I'm currently running Mahout's(version 0.8) Matrix Factorization Recommender on Hadoop using following

mahout recommendfactorized -i mahout_parallelALS_output/userRatings/ -o recommendations/ --userFeatures mahout_parallelALS_output/U/ --itemFeatures mahout_parallelALS_output/M/
--numRecommendations 10

which is taking extremely long time to complete map phase (over 4 hours but only completed 3% of the map jobs as of now.) and this seems to me very unusual. Can someone tell me if i'm doing it wrong or somehow to optimize the performance?

Comment: How many nodes are working and how are their configurations?

Comment: I'm running the job on 10 Amazon EMR m2.xlarge(2 CPU and 17GB RAM) nodes.

Comment: Just to have more information, how big is your data? Number of records, number of users, number of items, etc.

Comment: Number of records = 400 Million
Number of users = 5 Million
Number of records = 100 Million

Comment: @rusho1234: Were you able to get any clue on the issue. I am facing the same issue with recommendfactorized job.

Comment: @YashSharma i decided to use graphlab which seems to me a much better choice to do MF